# Python Pandas DataFrame - .apply works not as expected, leads to wrong results

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, timestamp, apply

I have a pandas DataFrame in Python and want to apply a specific function pointwise on the entries of the first column.
For this purpose, I used the .apply-Method of pd.Series.
But with the function I want to apply on the entries, it does not work.

---

In my minimal example, I have three functions:
istimestamp
istimestampandchange
isintandchange

The second function "istimestampandchange" cannot be applied pointwise to the dataframe column with .apply - this leads to wrong results.

---

With the two other functions, it works well.
So it is probably an issue of pd.Timestamp?

Many thanks for your ideas! :-)

Here the code:

```
import pandas as pd

def istimestamp(datum):
    isi = isinstance(datum, pd.Timestamp)
    print("Inside: " + str(isi) + "   for   " + str(datum))
    return isi

def istimestampandchange(datum): # This is the function for which .apply behaves unexpected:
    isi = isinstance(datum, pd.Timestamp)
    print("Inside: " + str(isi) + "   for   " + str(datum))
    if isi:
        datum = 0
    return datum

def isintandchange(number):
    isi = isinstance(number, int)
    print("Inside: " + str(isi) + "   for   " + str(number))
    if isi:
        number = 0
    return number


a = pd.Timestamp(year = 2024, month = 1, day = 1).tz_localize("Europe/Berlin")
b = pd.Timestamp(year = 2024, month = 1, day = 2).tz_localize("Europe/Berlin")
df = pd.DataFrame({"spalte" : [a,b]})

line = "="*48

print(line + "\nApplying istimestamp on each a and b:\n" + line)
print("Outside: " + str(istimestamp(a)))
print("Outside: " + str(istimestamp(b)))

print(line + "\nApplying on series leads to the same result:\n" + line)
apply1 = df["spalte"].apply(lambda datum : istimestamp(datum))
print("Outside: " + str(apply1))

print(line + "\nApplying istimestampandchange on each a and b:\n" + line)
print("Outside: " + str(istimestampandchange(a)))
print("Outside: " + str(istimestampandchange(b)))

print(line + "\nApplying on series leads !!! NOT !!! to the same result:\n" + line)
apply2 = df["spalte"].apply(lambda datum : istimestampandchange(datum))
print("Outside: " + str(apply2))

a = 2
b = 3
df = pd.DataFrame({"spalte" : [a,b]})

print(line + "\nApplying isintandchange on each a and b:\n" + line)
print("Outside: " + str(isintandchange(a)))
print("Outside: " + str(isintandchange(b)))

print(line + "\nApplying on series leads to the same result:\n" + line)
apply3 = df["spalte"].apply(lambda number : isintandchange(number))
print("Outside: " + str(apply3))
```

Here is the output:

```
================================================
Applying istimestamp on each a and b:
================================================
Inside: True   for   2024-01-01 00:00:00+01:00
Outside: True
Inside: True   for   2024-01-02 00:00:00+01:00
Outside: True
================================================
Applying on series leads to the same result:
================================================
Inside: False   for   DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-01 00:00:00+01:00', '2024-01-02 00:00:00+01:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]', freq=None)
Inside: True   for   2024-01-01 00:00:00+01:00
Inside: True   for   2024-01-02 00:00:00+01:00
Outside: 0    True
1    True
Name: spalte, dtype: object
================================================
Applying istimestampandchange on each a and b:
================================================
Inside: True   for   2024-01-01 00:00:00+01:00
Outside: 0
Inside: True   for   2024-01-02 00:00:00+01:00
Outside: 0
================================================
Applying on series leads !!! NOT !!! to the same result:
================================================
Inside: False   for   DatetimeIndex(['2024-01-01 00:00:00+01:00', '2024-01-02 00:00:00+01:00'], dtype='datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]', freq=None)
Outside: 0   2024-01-01 00:00:00+01:00
1   2024-01-02 00:00:00+01:00
Name: spalte, dtype: datetime64[ns, Europe/Berlin]
================================================
Applying isintandchange on each a and b:
================================================
Inside: True   for   2
Outside: 0
Inside: True   for   3
Outside: 0
================================================
Applying on series leads to the same result:
================================================
Inside: True   for   2
Inside: True   for   3
Outside: 0    0
1    0
Name: spalte, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).